# Does an Array variable point to itself?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, binding

I tried some code to check the behavior of array and pointers. Its as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int s[]={1,2};
int *b=s;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", s, &s, *s);
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", b ,&b, *b);
}
```

Initially I thought of pointers and array to be same BUT...
To my surprise the value of 's' and '&s' are SAME unlike 'b'. Does that mean an Array variable "points to itself?"

I am also now confused with what actually is a variable "name"? How its binding takes place with a location in memory? I am just unable to visualize things that go on there! 
And where in memory (RAM) is all the information stored at run time?

Comment: See the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: `main` should return an `int` (normally 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

Assume the following code:

```
int arr[10];
foo(arr);
```

In the call to the function `foo`, the expression `arr` is converted from type "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the address of the first element of `arr` is what actually gets passed to `foo`.

We would define `foo` as either

```
void foo(int a[]) {}
```

or

```
void foo(int *a) {}
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are identical to `T *a`; the parameter is a *pointer* type, not an array type.  Note that this is *only* true for function parameter declarations.

As mentioned above, one exception to this rule is when the array expression is the operand of the unary `&` operator.  If we change the call to `foo` to read

```
foo(&arr);
```

then the type of the expression `&arr` is "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[10]`, and the value of the expression is the address of `a`.  For this, the definition of `foo` would be

```
void foo(int (*a)[10]) {}
```

In C, **the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are the same** - thus both of the expressions `arr` and `&arr` have the same *value*, but their types are different.  This matters for operations involving pointer arithmetic.  For example, assume our code had been written

```
int arr[10];
foo(arr);
...
void foo(int *a)
{
   ...
   a++;  
   ...
}
```

On entry, `a` points to `arr[0]`.  The expression `a++` would advance the pointer to point to the next integer in the array (`arr[1]`).

Now assume the code had been written as

```
int arr[10];
foo(&arr);
...
void foo(int (*a)[10])
{
  ...
  a++;
  ...
}
```

On entry, `a` still points to `arr[0]` (remember, the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), but this time the expression `a++` will advance the pointer to point to the next *10-element array* of integers; instead of advancing the pointer `sizeof (int)` bytes, we advance it `sizeof (int[10])` bytes.

So this is why in your `printf` statement you see the same *values* for both `s` and `&s`.  You should use the `%p` conversion specifier to print pointer values, and it expects the corresponding argument to be type `void *`, so change those `printf` statements to

```
printf("%p %p %d\n", (void *) s, (void *) &s, *s);
printf("%p %p %d\n", (void *) b, (void *) &b, *b);
```

Answer (score 7):

OK, let say the following is how the memory looks when you execute

```
int s[]={1,2};
int *b=s;

s[]
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
100   104 
^
|
|  int *b = &s
+-----+
| 100 |
+-----+
200
```

`s` is an array. What that means is, it is a contiguous memory location which is associated with a variable `s` and each element is accessed by offsetting the array variable name.

So when you use `s` it actually boils down to the address of the array (which is `100` in this case). And when you do `*s`, it boils down to `*(s+0)` which is equivalent of `s[0]` and so `*s` represents the contents stored in the zeroth location (in this case `s[0]` is `1`). When do do an `&s`, this will print the address of the `s (which is`100` in this case).

Note that, here `s` and `&s` represents an address; `*s` and `s[x]` represents an integer.

The same applies to the pointer. So, `b` prints the content it has, which is the address of `s` (which is `100` in this case). `&b` prints the address of `b`, which is `200` in this case. And, `*b` prints the content of the first element of the array `s` which is `1`.

I have modified you program to make it print the address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s[]={1,2};
    int *b=s;
    printf("%p, %p, %d\n", (void *)s, (void *)&s, *s);
    printf("%p, %p, %d\n", (void *)b, (void *)&b, *b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xbfc4f3e4, 0xbfc4f3e4, 1
0xbfc4f3e4, 0xbfc4f3ec, 1
```

EDIT: `%p` expects `void *`. Added the same!

Answer (score 4):

An array, when used as an argument to a function, decays into a pointer to its first element. Similarly, taking the address of an array results in a pointer to the location of the first element (but with a different type).

As for your second question, a variable name only exists at compile-time. It typically has no representation in memory at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to think about this is that an array as a pointer can't be changed by assignment, it is effectively a constant pointer to a known amount of memory.

To try that, use:

```
myptr = myarray;
```

Which is perfectly ok, and then try:

```
myarray = myptr;
```

Which is not.

Comment: It may be a simple way to think about it, but it's also a wrong way to think about it.  An array is not a pointer, const or otherwise.  Saying that it is will only lead to more questions later, at which time, someone will have to explain to him that an array is in fact *not* a pointer, and he won't know who to believe.