# C Array Points to Itself

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have the following C code:

```
char arr[1];
printf("%p %p\n", &arr, arr);
```

The values of &arr and arr printed are always the same. This means that arr contains the location of itself.

If I dereference the array and write a value to it like so:

```
 *arr = 'a';
```

I expect it to overwrite the value in arr because arr points to itself.

But this doesn't happen. When I print the value of arr again:

```
printf("%p\n", arr);
```

It contains the same old value which is the location to itself.

Why doesn't arr get overwritten?

Edit: I tried the following links but none of them answered my question exactly:

[What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

[Does an Array variable point to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132835/does-an-array-variable-point-to-itself)

Comment: `char[1]` is useless for holding strings. It's only able to hold a NUL, no actual string data.

Comment: "This means that arr contains the location of itself." No. No it does not. It means C is interpreting it as a pointer given the `%p` placeholder.

Comment: Tip: use a debugger to show what's actually happening in memory visually.

Comment: Also be aware that `*x` is strictly equivalent to `x[0]` or more generally: `*(x + y)` is strictly equivalent to `x[y]`.

Comment: Do not confuse an array with a pointer. An array is a composite variable. It's a collection of variables under the name of the array. A pointer is one variable that contains a memory address. The answer you linked explains how arrays and pointers can be used interchangeably, although they are different things.

Comment: @tadman, not useless. It can handle `""` which is a perfectly valid C-string.

Comment: @tstanisl Valid, but the use cases for that are extremely slim. I'm speaking in general terms, not theoreticals.